# how to post an image to django with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I have a django model class like this:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField('date added', auto_now_add=True)
    modify_date = models.DateTimeField('date modified', auto_now=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image_file = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=get_image_filename, null=True, blank=True)
```

And the [rest framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) installed. I can post and create new locations via ajax (from the webpage) like this:

```
var config ={
        url: LOCATIONS_URL,
        type: 'POST',
        data :{ 
        name: 'new_name',
        },
        headers: { "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken") },
        success: function (context){console.log('success', context);},
        error: function (context){console.log('errror');},
    }
    $.ajax(config);
```

`getCookie("csrftoken")` is a function that gets the correct CSRF value. This works.

Now I want to post an image via ajax to the Django database. I tried various things for example:

```
var alt_logo = new Image();
var file;
alt_logo.addEventListener('load', function() {
      file = new File([alt_logo], "filename.png", {type: "image/png", lastModified: new Date()});
      var formData = new FormData(file);
      var config ={
                url: LOCATIONS_URL,
                type: 'POST',
                data :{ 
                    name: 'testname',
                    image_file: formData,
                },
                contentType:false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                headers: { "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken") },
                success: function (context){console.log('success', context);},
                error: function (xhr,ajaxOptions, thrownError)console.log( "Error: " + thrownError );console.log( "Status: " + status );},
            })
            alt_logo.src = 'path/to/my/default_logo.png';          
   }
   $.ajax(config);
```

But I always get the error "415 Unsupported Media Type".

After googleing around I tried to send the data as a JSON string with `JSON.stringify` but this leads to a "Bad request". My ajax call for that looked like this:

```
var config ={
            url: COMPANIES_URL,
            type: 'POST',
            data :{ 
                name: 'testname',
                image_file: JSON.stringify(formData),
            },
            contentType:'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            headers: { "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken") },
            success: function (context){console.log('success', context);},
            error: function (xhr,ajaxOptions, thrownError){console.log( "Error: " + thrownError );console.log( "Status: " + status );},
            }
 $.ajax(config);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you need `dataType: 'json'` ?

Comment: I tried that to in combination with the `JSON.stringify` which also resulted in a "bad request"